# How to change the default color of link in kendo editor from createLink button

Tags: javascript, css, kendo-ui, kendo-editor

```js
 $("#editor").kendoEditor({
            tools: ['createLink'],
            stylesheets: [
                "editorStyles.css"
            ]
        });
```

```css
.k-editor-link-url{
    color: green;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.620/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.620/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.620/styles/kendo.material.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.620/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.620/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<div id="example">

    <div class="box wide">
        <h4>Information</h4>
        <p>
            The following demo shows how to use the Editor's style tool, which provides the ability to customize the widget content by means of custom
            CSS classes and styling, and a CSS file registered in the Editor iframe document.
        </p>
    </div>
    <textarea id="editor" rows="10" cols="30" style="width:100%;height:400px">
    </textarea>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

I wanted to change the default color of the link which is blue to any other color
in KendoEditor.For example,if link is inserted by default it should be opened in some other color.I'm trying to change the link color from the blue to green while inserting link.But it is not changing

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The Editor applies some [default styles](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/editor/appearance#using-the-default-styles). Override the default style of the anchor tag to style the links in green - either in the stylesheet loaded in the Editor or by [overriding the default anchor tag styles](https://dojo.telerik.com/UnuBEXot).